# Remove application scrolling in ios Phonegap

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova, scroll, viewport

I am creating an Application in ios using Phonegap 2.2.0. When I build the example application given by Phonegap team, the build was success and the application running fine. But there is scroll by default due to status bar of iphone.

when I remove the status bar from application the scrolling of page is resolved but I need to display that stausbar in application.

How to remove that scroll without using  " touchmove and e.preventDefault()" methods.

Answer (score 0):

Set UIWebViewBounce to NO in Cordova.plist. You will find Cordova.plist under resources folder.

Comment: It is not working, I made that change already and tested multiple times.

Comment: can you share the contents of cordova.plist file here.

Comment: self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 480); Added this in 

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated

after self.view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];

now page scroll is Gone.